# Extracting all values of Y at specified levels of predictor variable in R

Tags: r

My data is of the form:

```
Y   X1   X2
4   1    0
7   0    1
2   0    0
3   0    0
7   1    1
...
```

Let's say I'd like to pull all the values of Y when X1 = 0 and X2 = 0, for example. I'd pull the values 2, 3, and any other values of Y corresponding to X1 = 0 and X2 = 0.

How do I write R code to do this?

Comment: `subset(your_data, X1 == 0 & X2 == 0, select = Y)`

Comment: Perfect, thank you!